# How do I access the Data Object created by the gulp-gray-matter plugin (when compiling html files with nunjucks)

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, nunjucks, yaml-front-matter

I am using [nunjucks-render](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nunjucks-render) as a front-end JavaScript templating engine.

I would like to read frontal matter data out of certain .nunjuck files and then use that data whilst compiling my .nunjuck (template) files into .html files.

After a bit of research I have found [gulp-gray-matter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-gray-matter) to be one of the faster and better frontal matter extraction plugins.

My question is: How do I now get access to the frontal matter data objects?

For example, I would write the frontal matter in a .nunjucks file as:

```
---
title: Welcome to ACME Co.
---

<title>{{ data.title }}</title>
```

Final HTML output should be:

```
<title>Welcome to ACME Co.</title>
```

My gulfile.js settings are as follows:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    nunjucks = require('gulp-nunjucks-render')
    gulpGrayMatter = require('gulp-gray-matter');

    gulp.task("nunjucks", function(){
        return gulp.src(src/templates/**/*.+(nunjucks|njk))
            .pipe(gulpGrayMatter()) //send files through gray-matter plugin to extract frontal-matter
            .pipe(nunjucks({
                path: src/templates
            })) 
            .pipe(gulp.dest(src));
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `gulp-gray-matter` stores all front matter data in the `data` property of each file in your stream.

Also by default `gulp-nunjucks-render` uses the data that is present in the `data` property of each file in your stream.

So you don't actually have to do anything fancy in your Gulpfile. This will work:

```
gulp.task('nunjucks', function(){
    return gulp.src('src/templates/**/*.nunjucks')
        .pipe(gulpGrayMatter())
        .pipe(nunjucks()) 
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```

You do have to correctly access the data in your `.nunjuck` templates however:

```
---
title: Welcome to ACME Co.
---

<title>{{ title }}</title>
```

Comment: Such a simple answer... and 4 hours later I can move on with my life. Thanks :)